# Scaling background image to set height and parent width

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to scale background-image with CSS only to a particular height in pixels and 100% of the parent container, which can change depending on the viewport width.

I've attempted using `background-size: inherit;` but it seems to just placing image as in `auto`

I event tried using:

```
background-size: 100vw 300px;
```

It doesn't seem to like the vw... Unfortunately I cannot use:

```
background-size: cover;
```

because it will crop from the bottom is the width of the container exceeds that of the image.

Comment: Can you include some HTML?

Comment: background-size: 100% 300px; and then you may have to use background-repeat depending on if you want it to repeat.

Comment: simply `background-size:100% 300px` ?

Comment: 100% will scale to 100% of the image. But I just realized I'm doing it all wrong. My image is SVG. I probably need to look if I can adjust some o its parameters.